# Storyboard Scene Editor vanished

Tags: xcode8

I'm still new to Xcode and developing iOS apps...when I was editing my storyboard, I somehow removed the menu that displays  the list of scenes (which defaults to the right side of the file navigator).

How do you bring this menu/view back up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want you must just click on the button at the bottom in yellow highlight:

[image]

Comment: Well now I feel dumb, I didn't realize that you could click on that. Thank you!

Comment: This happens ! Somtimes we get stuck in simple things that we don't see at first sight.